# H1 Tags Hiding on Scroll for Fixed Backgrounds

Tags: html, css

Currently, on scroll the Heading Two and Heading Three titles do not show.  How do I get each Heading to show that is on top of its respective background on scroll while keeping h1 titles and backgrounds fixed?

```css
.parallax {
      height: 100vh;
      display:flex;
      align-items: center;
      position:relative;
    }

    .bg1 {
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .bg2 {
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-image: url('https://placekitten.com/g/800/600');
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .bg3 {
      background-attachment: fixed;
      background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/1200/800');
        background-size: cover;
    }

    h1 {
      position:fixed;
      background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
      margin-left: 45px;
      padding: 10px 20px;
    }
```

```html
<section class="parallax bg1">
    <h1>Heading One</h1>
  </section>
  <section class="parallax bg2">
    <h1>Heading Two</h1>
  </section>
<section class="parallax bg3">
    <h1>Heading Three</h1>
</section>
```

Comment: Remove the `position:fixed` from the `h1` to start.

Comment: @Paulie_D that prevents the H1's from being fixed which is the goal

Comment: Then you'll have to rethink. Without the fixed positioning it's doing exactly what you want it to.

Comment: If you want **one** `h1` that *changes* when you scroll past it to another section, that's completely different issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D yes that's what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: I'm pretty certain you'll need Javscript for that. `position:fixed` is **only** related to the viewport...it has no relation to the content / size of the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

Just change the h1 position property to relative :)